# changes required in u-boot for lz4 compression?

Tags: u-boot

I am using 3.12 Kernel and u-boot. I have selected lz4 compression in "make menuconfig" for kernel.
any changes required in u-bbot side to support lz4 compression?

Comment: If you build a **zImage** file for your kernel, then that is a self-extracting image (that does not require external lz4 support).  Otherwise you seem to have no need for lz4 support in U-Boot.

Comment: I have done following steps.                                           **bold**
 1. Built u-boot image.
 2. built device tree.
 3. Selected lz4 compression in "make menuconfig" for kernel and built uImage.
 4. Flashed u-boot image , device tree binary and uImage. after power up board is booting fine.   **bold**
 
 my doubht here is whether lz4 compression is used while creating uImage and lz4 un-compression is used during uncompressing the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I have done following steps.

```
1. Built u-boot image.
2. built device tree.
3. Selected lz4 compression in "make menuconfig" for kernel and built uImage.
4. Flashed u-boot image , device tree binary and uImage. after power up board is booting fine.
```

I have checked the kernel build logs, I could see "piggy.lz4.o" was created.

LZ4     arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lz4
  AS      arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lz4.o

```
my doubht here is whether lz4 compression is used while creating uImage and lz4 un-compression is used during uncompressing the kernel.
```